# Mongo $redact this object is already an operator expression Error

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**My goal** is to subtract the current date from the stored date, and compared them to a saved interval value by the user.

I am running into the following error trying to use redact.

> MongoResultException: localhost:27017: this object is already an operator expression, and can't be used as a document expression (at '0')

My code looks like this:

```
    <?php

    $ops = array(

            array(
                '$redact' => array(
                    '$cond' => array(
                        'if' => array( 
                            '$gte' => array('$subtract' => array('$new Date()' , '$last_interacted_date'), '$reminder_interval')
                        ),
                        'then' => '$$KEEP',
                        'else' => '$$PRUNE'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

$results = $collection ->aggregate($ops);
```

For some reason the $subtract is causing this error. Why is the presence of subtract causing: "this object is already an operation expression'?

Answer (score 2):

`$new Date()` is not valid here. You want `MongoDate` or `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` appropriate to your driver instead.

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$redact' => array(
            '$cond' => array(
                'if' => array( 
                    '$gte' => array(
                        '$subtract' => array(
                            new UTCDateTime(round(microtime(true) * 1000)),
                            '$last_interacted_date'
                        ),
                        '$reminder_interval'
                    )
                ),
                'then' => '$$KEEP',
                'else' => '$$PRUNE'
            )
        )
    )
);

$results = $collection ->aggregate($ops);
```

The interpolation of the `Date` value actually happens in the "client" and "before" the aggregation pipeline is actually sent to the server. So you get the "milliseconds" as of "now" and send as a "BSON Date".

Note that this is "millseconds" in difference from the two BSON dates, so your "interval" needs to be in milliseconds, or otherwise do the math to convert further.

Comment: It still throws the '$this object oppression'. Btw $last_interacted_date is is a stored BSON date. Is that a problem?

Comment: @DevinDixon `$last_interacted_date` will be fine as long as it is a BSON date type. I suspect your problem now is that you are not typing this the same as how it's diplayed but probably wrapping `UTCDateTIme` in a "string". It's a PHP function, and just like I described it executes "before" the pipeline is sent to the server. Or did you `use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` first? Or are you in fact using the "legacy" driver, where you use `MongoDate` instead?

Comment: Actually what I am putting MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime and getting the current timestamp from that and passing in the variable. But the problem is actually not that. I dummied the query to just numbers with $subtract(10,20),30) and I am still getting the error. But the error goes away when I remove substract.

Comment: @DevinDixon No no no no NO. [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) takes a BSON Array. So in the shell that would just be `"$subtract": [ 10,20,30 ]` or in PHP notation as `'$subtract' => array(10,20,30)` which would yield `-40`. I have no idea what you are actually trying to do there, but it certainly isn't following the code you presented nor what was supplied in correction in the answer. Just follow the answer, and if you need additional math and cannot work that out then ["Ask another Question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: sorry if I was un clear in my last comment. My goal is to subtract 10 from 20 and then check if the result is greater than 30. So $gte => array($subtract(10,20),30) Sorry if I was't clear. But I was trying to say is for some reason the $subtract caused a 'this object is already an operator expression' even when whole numbers are used.

Comment: @DevinDixon Ask a different question, This answers what you actually asked, which was to get the difference of the current date and a stored date and the listing here does exactly that. When you have more questions to ask you post them. This is not a discussion thread and I've told you that already.

Comment: Lynn, thanks for your reply and your help. I understand that this is not a discussion thread, and while the your answer may shed some light, it doesn't answer the original question which was ' For some reason the $subtract is causing this error. Why is the presence of subtract causing: "this object is already an operation expression'?'. So would a new thread that ask the same thing be appropiate?

Comment: @DevinDixon The code works perfectly for me. It is noted in your responses that you are "changing" things though. You have been asked not to do that, and just run the code as is presented. There is no error in the listing presented here.